# Removing excess whitespace - CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created a form which includes a selection of won awards.

However due to the layout options (I'm using Hubspot) there is a large space between the awards and form.

You can see the form at: http://content.workbooks.com/free-trial-workbooks-crm?hs_preview=w1at_hmF-2371060669

**I'd like to remove the excess whitespace to achieve the following**: [image: http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/2015-01-22_1111.jpg]

Comment: Got any markup to share?

Comment: did u try anything? that whitespace is caused by iframe height

Comment: Thanks, if I reduce the iframe an ugly scroll bar displays (hence the original excess height), so it appears there is some whitespace in the iframe source. Any advice on how to remove this?

Comment: Show us your effort, an image alone isn't enough... show us your code, it's easier to take a look at it with some code then it is with just an image

Answer (score 1):

Use `height="325px"`:

```
<iframe src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Workbooks_Signup_Form?edition=trial"
        width="600px" height="325px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
        style="overflow: hidden;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, that looks good but shows an ugly scroll bar (hence the original excess height), so it appears there is some whitespace in the iframe source.

Any advice on how to remove this?

Comment: You already gave `scrolling="no"`, but if you still see scrolling, give a `style="overflow: hidden;"`

Comment: @PraveenKumar still have scrolling after adding `style="overflow: hidden;"`. Check and edit it using inspect element !!

Comment: @Junaid I am getting a different output. I am using Chrome latest version on Windows 7 with 1024 x 768 resolution.

Comment: What's your screen resolution buddy?

Comment: 1366 x 768 !! Well I updated my answer .. @PraveenKumar Please have a look at that. That solved the problem in all browser.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding style="overflow: hidden;" but the scroll bar still appears. Is there a solution without Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to lower the height of the iFrame.

Comment: Thanks Sjors, if I reduce the iframe an ugly scroll bar displays (hence the original excess height), so it appears there is some whitespace in the iframe source. Any advice on how to remove this?

Comment: You can set the 'scrolling' attribute on the iFrame to 'no' like this: scrolling="no" or use css: overflow: hidden;

Comment: Which browser are you using? Try adding this: iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {  
        display: none;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="iframeWithoutScroll" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Workbooks_Signup_Form?edition=trial"
        width="600px" height="320px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden">
</iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
iframe#iframeWithoutScroll html {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Well this SOLVE the problem !! Actually `html` set to `overflow: auto;`.

In some browser you might have scrolling. So for this [**go-to-here**](http://www.christersvensson.com/html-tool/iframe.htm).

Comment: O Yeah ... @PraveenKumar I was in hurry ... its unintentional ... Thanks for highlight :)

Comment: That's why I removed my downvote. Mistakes happen. No worries. But we shouldn't pass the mistakes to others! `:)` Hope you take it in a positive way.

Comment: Thanks! I actually wrapped it in a div (for another reason) and used overflow: hidden; which has seemed to have fixed the issue!